# How to use Amazon Cognito with S3 for web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have gone through official docs and various AWS blog, to create a web application using Cognito. Mostly all example are based on mobile app, not web app.
As per documentation i have created an Identity Pool and i am using Google auth provider. After this the AWS has given me following code -

Get AWS Credential-

```
       AWS.config.region = 'ap-northeast-1'; // Region
       AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
   });
```

Store User Data -

```
   AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
   var syncClient = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();
   syncClient.openOrCreateDataset('myDataset', function(err, dataset) {
   dataset.put('myKey', 'myValue', function(err, record){
   dataset.synchronize({
       onSuccess: function(data, newRecords) {
           // Your handler code here
       }
    });
  });
 });
});
```

From here i am clue less how to proceed. In my html page i have a login button, on click to the button which function i have to call, which basically invoke the google authenticator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These docs may be helpful for you with passing your google token to Amazon Cognito (make sure you select javascript as your language):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/google/

Overall, once you login you need set up your credentials with the google token:

```
 AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: {
       'accounts.google.com': authResult['id_token']
    }
 });
```

Once your credentials are set up, you should be able to call other services (that you give your users permissions to call).